# I can't stop a thread from running in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

As the title says, I cant seem to stop a thread from running.

Here are my two classes:

```
class MouseHandler implements MouseListener
{
    private Chronometer chronometer= new Chronometer();

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
        {
            if(Condition1)
            {
                chronometer.start();
                System.out.println("The Thread is started");
            }
            if(Condition2)
            {
                System.out.println("Stopping the Thread...");
                chronometer.stopRunning();
            }
            if(Condition3)
            {
                System.out.println("Stopping the Thread...");
                chronometer.stopRunning();
            }
        }
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

```
class Chronometer extends Thread
{
    private volatile boolean flag=true;
    public void stopRunning()
    {
        System.out.println("Method StopRunning entered");
        flag=false;
        System.out.println("Current flag value= " + flag);
    }
    public void run()
    {
        int sec=0;
        while(flag)
        {
            //static method that set the text of a JLabel
            setInitPanel.setChronText(sec);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sec++;
            System.out.println("The Thread is running...");
            System.out.println("Current flag value= " + flag);
        }
    }
}
```

The ifs in the MouseHandler class work perfectly. The output is:

```
The Thread is started
The Thread is running...
Current flag value= true
//condition2 or condition3 occurs
Stopping the Thread...
Method StopRunning is entered
Current flag value= false
The Thread is running...
Current flag value= true
The Thread is running...
Current flag value= true
The Thread is running...
Current flag value= true
The Thread is running...
Current flag value= true
//and it just keeps going
```

The `JLabel` actually change text when the Thread starts. But it never stops. I have also tried to use the `interrupt()` method in the ifs and `!isInterrupted()` in the while (inside the run method). This doesn't works either. I have also tried to make the same thing making the Chronometer class to implement Runnable. It doesn't works either. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure `Chronometer chronometer= new Chronometer()` is not one per instance? it should be shared it looks like

Comment: It wasn't, i fixed it. Thanks